# How to set readonly properties in a subclass?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, inheritance, parse-platform

`MyLoginViewController` is a subclass of `PFLogInViewController`.

`logInViewController` is an object of type `MyLogInViewController` in `MainViewController.m`

**i.e.**

```
//  MainViewController.m

    MyLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[MyLogInViewController alloc] init];
            logInViewController.delegate = self;
            logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | 
                                                     PFLogInFieldsTwitter | 
                                                    PFLogInFieldsFacebook | 
                                                PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | 
                                                PFLogInFieldsDismissButton;
```

As you can see the `fields property` is being set here in `MainViewController.m`

**I want to set this** in `MyLogInViewController`, so that every `MyLogInViewController` object has it set.

However, fields is of type `readonly`
As seen from : https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFLogInView.html#//api/name/fields

`@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) PFLogInFields fields`

1. How can I override this?
   (I have thought about using a custom getter - but don't know how to execute properly)
2. Is what I'm trying to do considered bad practice, if so, why?

**Edit**: Turns out I was looking at the [View](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFLogInView.html#//api/name/fields) Documentation not the [ViewController](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFLogInViewController.html#//api/name/fields) Documentation. Thanks to mrt for spotting this.

Comment: you can use the property from superclass and throw exception when someone tries to use set property.

Comment: Hi @KunalBalani, I want to set the fields property in MyLogInViewController, so that every MyLogInViewController object has it set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone did something readonly, and they know what they are doing, that probably means it really shouldn't be set outside of the class. However, there may still be some reasons to do what you want to do. Why don't you do that in init method though?

Edit:

The fields property in PFLogInViewController can be set. So you can do this in your MyLogInViewController class init method

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Do aditional init stuff
        self.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsTwitter | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton;
    }
    return self;
}
```

this way, you won't be interfering with the internals of the class.

Comment: `self = [super initWithFields:defaultFields];` so you're saying override the `PFLogInViewController` init method?!

Comment: Damn, I didn't notice that you were referring to the view not the controller in the link, my bad. I updated my answer. The view has it readonly, but it's readwrite in the controller class. So you can set that in your init method

Comment: Ah now it makes sense! I didn't realize I was looking at the View documentation. Then I would have copped to put it in the init. Very Nice. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) PFLogInFields fields
```

in your subclass?